# Deprecated roles from AccessDefinition class of Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I was checking the permissions property of `AppDescriptor` and found out that `getRoles` in the `AccessDefinition` is actually deprecated.  Does anyone know why is it deprecated? Does it mean that we shouldn't be setting the permission roles in the app? I asked this because my code will be wanting to get the roles defined in the app and I don't know if it's ok for me to use this one even if it's deprecated already.

The code from AccessDefinition.java:

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
Collection<String> getRoles();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that we shouldn't be setting the permission roles in the app?

No, you can set roles required for running the app alright.

Method was deprecated because it will just return roles configured to be necessary for running the app irrespective to whether overriding right for superuser to use the app was set or not.

`hasAccess(User user)` method was introduced to allow such checks on more complex rules (e.g. taking superuser overriding permissions into account or any other rules that custom implementation of `AccessDefinition` might want to introduce) and at the same time keeping `getRoles()` method ordinary (as in returning what was set with `setRoles(Collection<String> roles)`).

That's why.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting them under the `User` via the same method signature.

```
User.getRoles();
```

Comment: But I want to know the roles set for the content app, not the roles of the user. Actually upon checking further, I think it is deprecated because magnolia wants us to use the "boolean hasAccess(User var1)" function of AccessDefiniton and to never use the getRoles.